# Unable to return text within href (jSoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is a code snippet I am using to access "test" from below html snippet. How can I access the URL https://www.google.com from within html ?

```
Elements e = doc.getElementsByAttribute("href");
Iterator<Element> href = e.iterator();
    while ( href.hasNext() ){
    Element link = href.next();
    String text = link.text();
    }



   <a href="javascript:linkToExternalSite('https://www.google.com','','61x38pxls','','','','','')">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HREF is an attribute which you can access with the `attr`method of Jsoup's element. This gives you the whole content of the attribute, of course, you need some pattern matching to retrieve the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I am no Jsoup expert but Jsoup is an html parser you can't use it to parse content inside `javascript` tag.

So, your approach should be to extract

`"javascript:linkToExternalSite('https://www.google.com','','61x38pxls','','','','','')"`

using Jsoup.

Than use [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to fetch the content/url.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String html = "<a href=\"javascript:linkToExternalSite('https://www.google.com','','61x38pxls','','','','','')\">Test</a>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element e = doc.select("a[href]").first();
    String href = e.attr("href");   
    String arg[] = href.split("'");
    String url = arg[1];
    // Output: 'https://www.google.com'
    System.out.println(url);
```